Force the use one specific route
In Windows, I want to use one specific network interface with a specific gateway to reach one specific IP address, but I want this IP address to be unreachable if the network interface is down or if the gateway is not the default gateway.
I added a route with the command below.
netsh int ipv4 add route <remote IP>/32 <interface name> <gateway>

It works well when the interface is up and connected to the right network with the correct gateway.
But I have 2 issues:

If the interface is up and connected to another network that uses another gateway, the packet is going through the other gateway.  I guess that the system is trying to use another route to reach the first gateway.
If the interface is down, the route becomes inactive and another route is used.

I guess I cannot achieve want I want using routes only, correct?

Routing, by itself, focuses on creating connectivity, not blocking it.
Selectively blocking connectivity in order to implement administrative policies is the role of a firewall or firewall-like mechanisms, such as Access Control Lists (ACLs).
So your guess is right: Routing is not the way to achieve your goal of enforcing administrative policies that selectively break connectivity.
